# Pass parameter to arr.{function parameter} = property

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I would like to pass a parameter from the function into the array.[parameter here] = value
But i cannot seem to get this to work, any suggestions to fix this.

below is the code i have so far

```
    function editStyle(Style,element,value){
    var i = menu.style.findIndex(style => style.Name === Style);
    menu.style[i].[element] = value;}
```

Comment: There should be not `.` between the two bracket notation property accesses.

Comment: Thank you for the help :) your amasing